# hide columns in table based on values returned from checkboxes from ajax loaded table

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

i have a table which is loaded by ajax call
in ajax stop

```
        ajaxStop: function () {

        $.each($("input[class='check']:checkbox:not(:checked)"), function ()  {  // i think as i am using vsn4ik bootstrap checkbox my expression should be different
            debugger;
            var column = "table ." + $(this).attr("name");
            $(column).toggle();
            $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnFixedWidthCellTruncation;
            var search1 = $("#grid-selection").dataTable();

            search1.fnAdjustColumnSizing();

 }
```

i am disabling columns based on the value of bootstrap-checkboxes some of them are

```
    <input type="checkbox" class="check"  name="HELO" data-group-cls="btn-group-xs">&nbsp;hello

    <input type="checkbox" class="check"  name="HELO1" data-group-cls="btn-group-xs">&nbsp;hello1


    <input type="checkbox" class="check"  name="HELO2" data-group-cls="btn-group-xs">&nbsp;hello2
```

These checkboxes are not checked by default so i need to access these checkboxes so i am using the same class name for them to access them but i think something is wrong in this expression because it is not able to get those checkboxes which are not checked
     input[class='check']:checkbox:not(:checked)

Comment: are you getting any console errors while iterating?

Comment: no not any its that debugger is not hitting

Comment: i am using these checkboxes https://vsn4ik.github.io/bootstrap-checkbox/

Comment: please add a fiddle with your sources

Comment: Know that it makes no difference what checkboxes you are using, because the generated inputs are still of type `checkbox`. If your generated checkboxes are really like your examples, your selector is not the trouble. If you put the debugger before your `each` function, does it hit?

Comment: i put a debugger before $.each and it is hitting .all i want i to select all non checked bootstrap-checkbox